# Gmail API messages.modify 40x slower than IMAP?

Tags: python, imap, gmail-api

I'm creating an app to move messages around in a user's inbox. Currently I'm using the Gmail API to do so, but I've noticed that making requests to the API is markedly slower than using IMAP.

The method is straightforward: I'm sending a batch of modify requests to change the labels on a group of emails in order to move them around. My message throughput using the Gmail API is 3.3 messages/second. For comparison, IMAP throughput is 130 messages/second.

Here's how I'm currently using BatchHttpRequests:

```
batch = BatchHttpRequest()
for gmailId in gmailIds:
    batch.add(self.service.users().messages().modify(userId=self.user.email, id=gmailId, body=labels))
try:
    batch.execute()
except errors.HttpError, error:
    log_this_error(self.user.email, error.resp.status)
```

and here is my IMAP code that accomplishes the same task:

```
# imap_conn is the user's authed connection
status, count = imap_conn.select(oldMailboxLabel)
if status == "OK":
    count = int(count[0])
    if count > 0:
        messageNumbers = range(1, count + 1)
        messageNumbers = ",".join(map(str, messageNumbers))
        imap_conn.copy(messageNumbers, newMailboxLabel)
        imap_conn.close()
        imap_conn.delete(oldMailboxLabel)
    else:
        imap_conn.close()
else:
    count = 0
```

I'm already batching and gzipping my requests, and I've tried using fields to limit the amount of information that is returned. All of which is suggested on their [performance tips](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/performance) page. I'm struggling to understand why the requests take so long to complete. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you show your IMAP code for comparison? Also, what language are you writing in? Looks like it might be Python?

Comment: Hi @Schwern, I've added the IMAP code to compare. And yes, I'm writing in Python-- my bad if that wasn't clear before! I'm finding it very weird that IMAP has a better message throughput than the Gmail API

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the GMail API you seem to be doing it "right". I'm going to guess that because GMail is itself a mail client the GMail API is targeted at writing toy mail clients while IMAP is better designed for the efficient bulk work of a fully functional mail client.

If you're moving *every* message from an old label to a new label, perhaps instead [rename the label using Users.labels.update](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/update)?

If not, you can reduce the number of requests by doing by [by thread](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/modify) instead of by message.

Or just use IMAP.